# How to use a javascript variable within an html td id

Tags: javascript, html, django

In order to check cells in my table for whether they contain a value in javascript, it seems I need to give each td an id. I'll have thousands of cells, so typing out each td with its id isn't possible.

Currently the trs with all the tds are generated with a loop in html, so with javascript I wanted to add a variable and stick it on the end of each id.

I've managed to get a javascript variable into my html loop and it's correctly counting up, but my issue is getting it into the id="___" part.

As shown in the code below, I've tried putting the document.write(i) line into the id, but it seems to treat it just as normal text. I've also put it in the output for DataEntryStatus just to prove that it's counting correctly, starting at 1 and increasing with each new row.

```
<table class="table" id="table_id">
    <tr>
        <th style="color:#ddd">fffffffffffffff<br>f<br>f<br>f</th>
        <th style="vertical-align:bottom;">Data Entry Status</th>
        <th style="vertical-align:bottom;">Tool</th>
    </tr>


<tbody id="myTable">

<script>
    var i = 1;    
</script>
{% for item in items %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="{% url 'edit_newcuts' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">Edit</a>
            <a href="{% url 'delete_newcuts' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">! X !</a>
        </td>

        <td id="DataEntryStatus"><div>{{ item.DataEntryStatus }} <script>document.write(i)</script></div></td>
        <td id="Tool + <script>document.write(i)</script>"><div>{{ item.Tool }}</div></td>
    </tr>

<script>
    i = i + 1;    
</script>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

And my javascript:

```
    $('#table_id tr').each(function(){
    if($('#Tool' + 'i').text() =="")$('#DataEntryStatus' + 'i').text("Entry missing");
    else if($('#CutRef' + 'i').text() =="")$('#DataEntryStatus' + 'i').text("Entry missing");
    else($('#DataEntryStatus' + 'i').text("Complete"));


    if($(this).text().toLowerCase() =="entry missing")$("#DataEntryStatus").css('background-color','#fcc');
    if($(this).text().toLowerCase() =="complete")$("#DataEntryStatus").css('background-color','#af0');
});
```

I want something like my id="Tool + document.write(i)" line to make ids like Tool1, Tool2, ... but right now it's treating + document.write(i) as normal text and I don't know how to get it to work as a script.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "loop in HTML". You're already using variables in your loop in whatever templating language this is; use something from the `item`, like the `item.pk`, to generate a unique ID for the table cell. The `i` you've declared in JS has nothing to do with the template context.

Comment: Blue - which template language are you using? I thought it was Twig, but is that Django?

Comment: @James Long I'm using Django, yes. I didn't quite realize what a template language is until now.

Comment: Generally speaking, forget that `document.write()` exists.  It doesn't add anything to the existing document - it blanks it and writes a new one.  It's rare that you'll actually want to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using Django, so why not just add the ID using that?

```
<table class="table" id="table_id">
    <tr>
        <th style="color:#ddd">fffffffffffffff<br>f<br>f<br>f</th>
        <th style="vertical-align:bottom;">Data Entry Status</th>
        <th style="vertical-align:bottom;">Tool</th>
    </tr>


<tbody id="myTable">

{% for item in items %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="{% url 'edit_newcuts' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button">Edit</a>
            <a href="{% url 'delete_newcuts' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">! X !</a>
        </td>

        <td id="DataEntryStatus{{ forloop.counter0 }}"><div>{{ item.DataEntryStatus }}</div></td>
        <td id="Tool{{ forloop.counter0 }}"><div>{{ item.Tool }}</div></td>
    </tr>

{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

[Django has a `forloop` variable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#for) inside loops that gives you access to the current index.

**Update**

To use that with JavaScript, change `counter` to `counter0`. This is now the same as an index within a JavaScript loop.

You'd access that by looping through with `.each` as you have been, but with a slight modification.

```
$('#table_id tr').each(function(i){
    if($('#Tool' + i).text() =="")$('#DataEntryStatus' + i).text("Entry missing");
    else if($('#CutRef' + i).text() =="")$('#DataEntryStatus' + i).text("Entry missing");
    else($('#DataEntryStatus' + i).text("Complete"));


    if($(this).text().toLowerCase() =="entry missing")$("#DataEntryStatus").css('background-color','#fcc');
    if($(this).text().toLowerCase() =="complete")$("#DataEntryStatus").css('background-color','#af0');
});
```

Comment: @Blue I think you're using Django. I've updated my code for that. That should give you unique IDs for your `<td>`s

Comment: So how would I call this forloop.counter value into the javascript? With the line currently as if($('#Tool' + 'i').text() =="")$("#DataEntryStatus").text("Entry missing"); would it be changed to something like if($('#Tool{{ forloop.counter }}').text() =="")$("#DataEntryStatus").text("Entry missing");?

Comment: @Blue try something like that

Comment: Seems javascript doesn't have access to the forloop.counter value, but I just set up a separate loop in it to count the same way and it all works! Many thanks

Comment: @Blue glad to help. Welcome to Stack Overflow